# Confused on Document Based iPhone App Guide

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, document-based

I'm writing one of my first iPhone apps - a simple way of remembering things about people. I'm following the iOS document called "[Document-Based App Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)" and I've gotten to the point where we query the local device and iCloud to detect and load documents. In the guide they use a custom class and since they don't show the code for the class, I'm confused on what it should look like. They give this description of the custom class "FileRepresentation":

> The example application now has an array (_fileList) of custom model
>   objects that encapsulate the name and file URL of each of the
>   application’s documents. (FileRepresentation is the custom class of
>   those objects.)

***Can anyone give an example of what "FileRepresentation"'s class implementation would look like?***

The parts are Listing 4-3 and 4-4 on the page "[Managing the Lifecycle of a Document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/ManageDocumentLifeCycle/ManageDocumentLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH4-SW1)":

**Listing 4-3**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // set up Add and Edit navigation items here....
    if (self.documentsInCloud) {
        _query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
        [_query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope, nil]];
        [_query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE '*.txt'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey]];
        NSNotificationCenter* notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(fileListReceived)
            name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:nil];
        [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(fileListReceived)
            name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:nil];
        [_query startQuery];
    } else {
        NSArray* localDocuments = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:
            [self.documentsDir path] error:nil];
        for (NSString* document in localDocuments) {
            [_fileList addObject:[[[FileRepresentation alloc] initWithFileName:[document lastPathComponent]
            url:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[self.documentsDir path]
            stringByAppendingPathComponent:document]]] autorelease]];
        }
    }
}
```

**Listing 4-4**

```
-(void)fileListReceived {
     NSString* selectedFileName=nil;
     NSInteger newSelectionRow = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;
     if (newSelectionRow != NSNotFound) {
        selectedFileName = [[_fileList objectAtIndex:newSelectionRow] fileName];
     }
     [_fileList removeAllObjects];
     NSArray* queryResults = [_query results];
     for (NSMetadataItem* result in queryResults) {
         NSString* fileName = [result valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemFSNameKey];
         if (selectedFileName && [selectedFileName isEqualToString:fileName]) {
             newSelectionRow = [_fileList count];
         }
         [_fileList addObject:[[[FileRepresentation alloc] initWithFileName:fileName
             url:[result valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey]] autorelease]];
     }
     [self.tableView reloadData];
     if (newSelectionRow != NSNotFound) {
         NSIndexPath* selectionPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newSelectionRow inSection:0];
         [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectionPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people that see this in the future, this is what I worked out by seeing how other classes implement their `init` functions:

```
#import "FileRepresentation.h"

@implementation FileRepresentation

@synthesize fileName = _fileName, fileUrl=_fileUrl;

-(id) initWithFileName:(NSString*)fileName url:(NSURL*)url
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.fileName = fileName;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Probably one of Apple's worst documents.